# payUmoney payment integration

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I tried payUMoney integration with an android application. I have searched many things on the internet but I did not find any solution.

Can anybody suggest me on how to integrate payUMoney in my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how  i integrated Payu money with my App , below is the code.
edit the code with your murchent key , salt and the success , failure url.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    WebView webviewPayment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webviewPayment = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPayment);
        webviewPayment.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewPayment.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webviewPayment.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webviewPayment.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        StringBuilder url_s = new StringBuilder();

        url_s.append("https://test.payu.in/_payment");

        Log.e(TAG, "call url " + url_s);


        webviewPayment.postUrl(url_s.toString(),EncodingUtils.getBytes(getPostString(), "utf-8"));



        webviewPayment.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception caught!");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private String getPostString()
    {
        String key  = "enter key";
        String salt  = "enter salt";
        String txnid = "TXN_1";
        String amount = "200";
        String firstname = "prada";
        String email = "a@b.com";
        String productInfo = "Product1"; 

        StringBuilder post = new StringBuilder();
        post.append("key=");
        post.append(key);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("txnid=");
        post.append(txnid);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("amount=");
        post.append(amount);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("productinfo=");
        post.append(productInfo);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("firstname=");
        post.append(firstname);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("email=");
        post.append(email);
        post.append("&");
        post.append("phone=");
        post.append("8904896130");
        post.append("&");
        post.append("surl=");
        post.append("http://Success.com/");
        post.append("&");
        post.append("furl=");
        post.append("http://failure.com/");
        post.append("&");

        StringBuilder checkSumStr = new StringBuilder();

        MessageDigest digest=null;
        String hash;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");

            checkSumStr.append(key);
            checkSumStr.append("|");
            checkSumStr.append(txnid);
            checkSumStr.append("|");
            checkSumStr.append(amount);
            checkSumStr.append("|");
            checkSumStr.append(productInfo);
            checkSumStr.append("|");
            checkSumStr.append(firstname);
            checkSumStr.append("|");
            checkSumStr.append(email);
            checkSumStr.append("|||||||||||");
            checkSumStr.append(salt);

            digest.update(checkSumStr.toString().getBytes());

            hash = bytesToHexString(digest.digest());
            post.append("hash=");
            post.append(hash);
            post.append("&");
            Log.i(TAG, "SHA result is " + hash);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        post.append("service_provider=");
        post.append("payu_paisa");
        return post.toString(); 
    }

    private JSONObject getProductInfo()
    {
        try {

            JSONObject productInfo = new JSONObject();

            JSONObject jsonPaymentPart = new JSONObject();
            jsonPaymentPart.put("name", "TapFood");
            jsonPaymentPart.put("description", "Lunchcombo");
            jsonPaymentPart.put("value", "500");
            jsonPaymentPart.put("isRequired", "true");
            jsonPaymentPart.put("settlementEvent", "EmailConfirmation");


            JSONArray jsonPaymentPartsArr = new JSONArray();
            jsonPaymentPartsArr.put(jsonPaymentPart);


            JSONObject jsonPaymentIdent = new JSONObject();
            jsonPaymentIdent.put("field", "CompletionDate");
            jsonPaymentIdent.put("value", "31/10/2012");


            JSONArray jsonPaymentIdentArr = new JSONArray();
            jsonPaymentIdentArr.put(jsonPaymentIdent);

            productInfo.put("paymentParts", jsonPaymentPartsArr);
            productInfo.put("paymentIdentifiers", jsonPaymentIdentArr);

            Log.e(TAG, "product Info = " + productInfo.toString());
            return productInfo;


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(hex);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: How to integeration payumoney in angular6/7/8 website?

Answer (score 0):

PayU integration part from front end:

```
String postData = "firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + ""
                            + "&surl=" + sucess_url + "&phone=" + phone
                            + "&key=" + key + "&hash=" + hash + "&curl=" + ""
                            + "&furl=" + failure_url + "&txnid=" + txnid
                            + "&productinfo=" + productinfo + "&amount="
                            + amount + "&email=" + email + "&pg="
                            + "CC" + "&drop_category="
                            + "NB";



browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

browser.postUrl(action,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
```

Please check [this link](http://www.edugcet.in/franchisee_download/7c8660cce1870f606064ff76c258d76d.pdf) for details.

`pg` = which tab you want to be open default on PayUMoney

(E.g.: NB = Net Banking, CC = Credit Card, DC = Debit card and EMI)

`drop_category` = comma-separated list of the payment options to be dropped from the payment page. For example, CC. NB drops credit card and netbanking options and displays only debit card option.

Comment: So now I Should Pass postData string to webview url right? @Anu Roy

Comment: yes..                                                                                                             WebView browser;                                                                                                                   browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

browser.postUrl(action,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));

Comment: I am passing all compulsory strings in URL with encrypted hash but its response is "Please ensure that you are using correct key and salt in transaction request".and my merchant key and salt are correct @Anu Roy

Comment: can you share the whole class code, It would be very helpful

Comment: How to integeration payumoney in angular 6/7/8 website?